# Message Queue with offline clients support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, queue, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

is there any message queue(MSMQ,RabbitMQ and so on..) with ruby bindings avalible that supports offline clients - by offline clients I mean that if i have a client submitting messages to the server,and it is unreachable,the client will hold the messages in an internal queue untill it gets connected again.

Is there some open source solution for that?
It seems that rabbitMQ does not do this,i might be wrong tho.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: xmpp has an addon for offline message support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with RabbitMQ if you are prepared to stick a broker on each machine, and then have them connect to your central broker with the shovel. Each machine then queues locally when offline. It's more hassle to run though.

Comment: RabbitMQ doesnt have to be the solution,is there something lighter? simpler?

Comment: The general pattern for durability is that the client writes to a durable queue on a local server. This seems to be the case in all message queue products I've encountered. TIBCO Rendezvous has true client side durability using a ledger file as part of the client library. I'm not sure if that fits your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

RabbitMQ does this.  http://rubyamqp.info/articles/durability/

Comment: From what i read - its the queues on the server that get persisted,what if a client is trying to send a message to a queue, but the broker is offline/unreachable,i would like this message to be persisted on the client side untill the server is reachable again